# Defer digest until Firebase .set().then() complete

Tags: angularjs, promise

This might be more a promise misunderstanding, but I'm stuck with a situation in which I'm calling `firebaseRef.set(this.myData).then(this.resolve)` in a directive child controller function.  In `.then(this.resolve)`, the `this.resolve()` function calls a parent controller function (bound with '&'), but the model changes are not `$digest()`ed.  I've tried returning a promise from `save()` using `$q`, but that did not help.  Here is `save()`:

```
this.save = () => {
    const chorePath = `chores/${member.$id}/${this.chore.$id}`;
    $root.user.$ref.child(chorePath)
      .set(this.chore)
      .then(this.resolve);
  }
};
```

Here is the directive where `resolve()` is bound

```
<chore-editor chore="$ctrl.selectedChore"
              resolve="$ctrl.choreSaved()"></chore-editor>
```

And then here's the `choreSaved()` function

```
this.choreSaved = () => {      
  this.editing = false;
};
```

`this.editing = false;` should hide the modal popup, but it doesn't because `$digest()` is not triggered.  The next `$digest()` cycle does hide the modal (triggered by clicking on anything model bound).  Is there a way I can structure this to allow angular to properly `$digest()` after the async `.set()` call?  Here's a picture that I think describes my issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$scope.$apply() or $rootScope.$apply()

Just for knowledge, you can look into angular source and see that `$timeout`, `ngClick`, `ngBlur` and other directives after doing some stuff always call `$apply`. Thats why usually you do not need to call it manually.

Comment: You definitely want to litter that all over your code base... /s

Comment: I wrapped the whole function in `$q()` without success because there was no `.then()`, so angular did not do an `$apply()`.  I wanted to avoid putting `$apply()` in the called resolve function, but it didn't occur to me to add it to the `then()` function body.  That was the simplest approach.

```.then(() => this.resolve(); $scope.$apply(); );```